# how to implement platform independent serialization?

Tags: json, cross-platform

How to implement platform independent serialization? I mean if i serialize an c++ object using json(c++ library) can it be deserialized by json(java library) as java object? or is there any other best approach for platform independent serialization?

Comment: JSON would be a reasonable choice, yes. It's well supported by pretty much all (popular) programming languages now. Your exact choice would depend on your exact requirements. Particularly whether or not performance was an issue.

Comment: To obtain best performance what could be the best choice? my requirement is i need to write the objects on the network and read them back from the network.

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers. If it's good enough for Google ...